# Checklist with Icons

Tags: 2010, web-part, bi

I have a SharePoint 2010 BI Requirement.

I have a custom checklist with over 100 columns.  Each item (column) in the list has a status of either complete or incomplete. The default value is incomplete.  There will be only 8-12 rows.  The title field will be the row identifier.  Several of the items have steps that need to be completed in order for the entire item to be complete.  In other words, sub-steps.  So I have a calculated column that has an IF statement (if steps 1 through x are complete, then display complete in that column, otherwise incomplete).

Example: Checklist item 5 has three sub items.  When all three have been completed, then item 5 displays complete.

What I need to do is show each of these columns as a graphic icon.  Unfortunately,  I cannot have that many calculated columns to produce this effect.  See [this](http://webmail.nc.rr.com/do/redirect?url=http%253A%252F%252Ftechnet.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Flibrary%252Fcc262787.aspx).

I have worked with SharePoint Designer and the conditional formatting is painful!!!  Plus it only works for one particular view.  I need to be able to display the icons in different web part views.

Also, the client doesn't want to use the KPI list as that it only displays down the page and not across.

Since I am not a code writer, I am posting this for SharePoint Community to lend some assistance.  Any takers?

Comment: If you're open to 3rd party solutions and want something a bit easier to use that SPD then this may help http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/highlighter

Answer (score 1):

I've used a dataview web part before to display my own KPI indicators (from _layouts/images) and percentages of completion of groups of items based on a parent item or piece of metadata. It wasn't too difficult to pull off, but it did get tricky at times.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use this script to catch the Check and Uncheck event of the checkbox and then show and hide the respective image tag based off that event.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#Checkbox').click(function(){
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        if(checked_status == true) {
            $('#txt').show();
        }
        else { $('#txt').hide();
        }
    }); </script>
```

Comment: I am not sure how this helps answer the OP's question - what am I missing?

Comment: He simply wants to show an Icon next to a field. I am simply showing him how to modify the HTML to apply an IMG tag next to the Table. I can't give a complete solution because I don't have the code but he just needs to modify the HTML to his liking.

Comment: She wants the icons on a View I believe and they should be dynamic depending on the 'check' status, not static.

Comment: Check out the updated answer

Comment: Thats not going to work on a *view* - just a form. Even then it will only work on a custom form that has #Checkbox and #txt elements already setup so is only half an answer. Sorry if I am giving you a hard time - not picking on you I just don't see how this helps the OP.

Comment: Yeah right! Evidently if Item 5 displays she has an id to that item #checkbox and #txt are just for demonstration purposes these would be replaced with the ID's of the hidden elements. When the element is shown she can call the javascript function to check if the element is checked or not and then display the image accordingly. I do not see how this is not answering the question. Unless she wants me to give a complete solution. I hope she can figure this out from there it is not that hard. This solution requires a custom form.

Comment: Ryan since you know how to solve the issue evidently. Please suggest an answer.